# How could this character fly?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* movie, we saw

> Red Skull guarding the Soul Stone on the planet Varmir.

We also saw that he was flying/floating. Provided that he was a human, how could he do that?

Comment: With great panache...

Comment: He fell towards the ground but missed...

Comment: You'll believe a nazi can fly.

Comment: he contains much hot air

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In short, he's no longer human. The Soul Stone has trapped him and is basically making him into its guardian.

> **What was the decision making process to bring Red Skull back?**
>
> **Joe Russo:** *Somebody had to be the gatekeeper to the Soul Stone and somebody had to distribute the rules to Thanos and Gamora. ...  Who
> felt credible to the audience. And **a character who has been trapped –
> the Red Skull has been turned into this wraith who now guards the Soul
> Stone and distributes the rules to whoever shows up there trying to
> obtain it.** It felt like there was more credibility than just a random
> character. ... Ross Marquand did an incredible job of capturing not only the essence of his voice, but the essence of the performance – **a haunted figure who is now this imprisoned spirit.***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Russo Brothers On That Surprise Return Of A Character In ‘Avengers: Infinity War’](https://uproxx.com/movies/russo-brothers-avengers-infinity-war-red-skull/)</sup></sub>